# Variable is not defined, but when I console log variable work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a style file and I import size from another style file in this file. When I try to use this variable I get the error "CARD_WIDTH is not defined",

Here it is the code:

```
import { SxProps, Theme } from '@mui/material';

import { CARD_WIDTH } from '../styles';

const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
    card: {
      background:
        theme.palette.mode === 'dark'
          ? 'black'
          : 'white',
      position: 'relative',
      cursor: 'grab',
      borderTop: '4px solid ',
      borderColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'primary.main' : '#8C8C8C',
      overflow: 'unset',
      marginBottom: '24px',
      width: CARD_WIDTH,
  } satisfies SxProps<Theme>)}

export default styles;
```

but if I add this code line before return object:

```
import { SxProps, Theme } from '@mui/material';

import { CARD_WIDTH } from '../styles';

const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
   console.log(CARD_WIDTH);

   return ({
    card: {
      background:
        theme.palette.mode === 'dark'
          ? 'black'
          : 'white',
      position: 'relative',
      cursor: 'grab',
      borderTop: '4px solid ',
      borderColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'primary.main' : '#8C8C8C',
      overflow: 'unset',
      marginBottom: '24px',
      width: CARD_WIDTH,
    }
  } satisfies SxProps<Theme>);
}

export default styles;
```

The error disappears

Can someone tell me how it works and what is this behaviour

Comment: what is the `satisfies` keyword for, and i see to little closing `}`.

Comment: is your CARD_WIDTH return an appropriate value?

Comment: yea, it CARD_WIDTH = 360